# Search for contacts by phone number

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there currently a way to query the Microsoft Graph for contacts by phone number. I see that it is possible to filter contacts by the 'mobilePhone' field, but not by 'businessPhones' or 'homePhones' fields. Any way to search in all those fields at once? That would be handy!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's a way to do this currently.  It doesn't look like filtering is supported on those collections.  We'll need to go back and see whether we can add filtering support for these attributes.

Comment: It'd be great if you could add filtering to those collections as well. I'm in a scenario where I have to look up contacts by phone number but many people store phone numbers under as 'Business' in O365. Thanks Dan! I hope you can convince the team to add support for this. :)