# Office 365 API: Search for contacts by phone number

Tags: office365

Is there currently a way to query the Microsoft Graph for contacts/Users by phone number. By 'businessPhones' or 'homePhones' fields. Any way to search in all those fields at once?

Comment: If my reply helps you, please mark the reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no way to do this currently. It doesn't look like filtering is supported on those collections.

For more information, please review the following link:

[Search for contacts by phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751747/search-for-contacts-by-phone-number)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a way? The answer says "It seems like there's a way to do this currently". Can you please clarify?

Comment: @PriyaKuppuswamiSorry,There seems to be no way to do this at the moment.My mistake.